# Foreach frmCustomForm in Application.OpenForms

Tags: c#, winforms, foreach

I'm trying to search through open forms looking for specific types of form [for example `frmMain`] in `Application.OpenForms` so I can call a function specific to that form type

```
    foreach (frmMain mainForm in Application.OpenForms)
    {
        // code stuff
    }
```

this does things correctly when it finds the correct type of form, but when it tries other types of form, instead of not considering them it tries to pass them, and it says

> Unable to cast object of type Project.frmNotMain' to type
>   'Project.frmMain'.

how do I stop the foreach from trying to pass the wrong forms?

I have tried

```
    foreach (frmMain mainForm in Application.OpenForms["frmMain"])
```

and

```
    foreach (frmMain mainform in Application.OpenForms.OfType<frmMain>)
```

both don't work because the foreach cannot operate on a 'method group'.

Comment: `OfType<frmMain>()` - add `()` since `OfType` is a *method*, not *property*

Answer (score 2):

Since `OfType<T>`is a *method* (not *property*) you should add `()` when you want to *execute* it:

```
  foreach (frmMain mainform in Application.OpenForms.OfType<frmMain>()) {
    // code stuff
  }
```

In case you have at most *one* instance of `frmMain` ("main" usually means "one" - among many a form just one is "main") you can simplify the loop into

```
  // Either instance of frmMain or null
  frmMain mainform = Application.OpenForms
    .OfType<frmMain>()      
    .FirstOrDefault();
```